# Jquery 2 dropdown lists, remove selected item 1 from dropdown 2

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, hide, clone

I have a simple form with 2 dropdown lists, each dropdown has the same values.

```
      <option value="attr1">attr1</option>
      <option value="attr2">attr2</option>
      <option value="attr3">attr3</option>
```

(this is just an example of the list, it may have 50+ entries)

If in DropDown list 1, I select `attr1` how do I hide that from dropdown list 2 ?

If I select another option from dropdown list one, then attr1 would need adding back and the newly selected item hidden from dropdown 2.

To make this harder, I'm cloning the TR containing the dropdown lists.

I'm using the code in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/1/)** to clone dropdown lists on a form.

So on a new cloned row, I would need it to be independant from the other rows, in that what is selected in it's dropdown list only affects it's dropdown list 2.

I've no idea where to start with this, but will be searching to see what I find.

Has anyone any pointers or examples of doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: updated the fiddle please check http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/3/

Comment: full script jsfiddle see this link http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/5/

Comment: @FrebinFrancis - Thanks that seems to work, anyway to hide attr1 as the default entry on the second list ? if it's selected on the first list ?

It seems to stay until you refresh the second list..

Comment: can i post it as an answer?

Comment: Please do and I'll accept it. Thx

Comment: thanks. i posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write this on the change event of select element.

```
$("#BoxName").change(function(){
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();   
        var nextDropdown = $(this).parent("td").next("td").find("select.BoxComparisonClass");

        $(nextDropdown).find("option").show();
        $(nextDropdown).find("option:[value="+selectedItem+"]" ).hide();
    });
```

See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/5/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I had to make one slight change for this to work for me. `$(nextDropdown).find("option[value='" + selectedItem + "']").hide();`

Comment: Just found this doesn't work in IE or Safari. Any way to get it to work ?